# ember js component init different function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a 'test-test' component which include 2 function like below:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    myfunction1: Ember.on('init', function() {
       alert(123);
        }),

    myfunction2: Ember.on('init', function() {
       alert(1234);
        }),

});
```

On the Application.hbs I call

```
{{#test-test}}{{/test-test}}
```

Of course the result will be 2 alert(123) and alert(1234).

What should I do if I want it to init only 1 function such as myfunction1 and do not init myfunction2?

Comment: Change myfunction2 to `myfunction2() { alert(1234); }`?

Comment: maybe you want to have a different function fire on `init`, and this other function will determine which functions should run?

Comment: but I need no keep Ember.on('init' ... to make this function auto run on load .. I think the problem is the way I call {{#test-test}} but I dont know how to fix that

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: yes you are right

Comment: this function can have a param which you either pass these other functions or maybe a config json which it consumes to determine what to do

Comment: Yes that is what I want to ask about. I want to create a component that includes all script function .. And I will just have to call it when it is needed

Comment: FYI, using `on('init')`, or `on` other lifecycle hooks is considered a bad practice because event handlers are asynchronous, so it leads to subtle bugs due to unexpected execution order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it that way:

```
//component/test-test.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

   whatToDoOnInit: null,

   initFunctions: Ember.on('init', function() {
      switch(this.get('whatToDoOnInit')) {
           case 1:
                 alert('123');
                 break;
           //...and so on
      }
   }),

});
```

and call it like that:

```
//template.hbs
{{#test-test whatToDoOnInit=1}}{{/test-test}}
```

Of course this way you could implement another logic:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

   doOneThing: false,
   doAnotherThing: true,

   initFunctions: Ember.on('init', function() {
      if(this.get('doOneThing')) {
           alert('123');
      }
      //...
   }),

});

//template.hbs
{{#test-test doOneThing=true doAnotherThing=false}}{{/test-test}}
```